# php filter json array by two attributes

Tags: php, json

I have a json array in a json file, this is brought into a `$data` variable `$data = file_get_contents("json/data.json");`. Two of the attribute names are `commonName` and `elementName`, these will be passed through the url.

With the json file in the `data` variable I would like to filter on two attributes and then echo the result.

I'm getting the following error:

```
Warning: array_filter() expects parameter 1 to be array, string given in
```

Here's my current code:

```
<?php
  function myfilter($row){
      return ($row['commonName']=='goat' && $row['elementName']=='calcaneus');
  }
  $result = array_filter($data, 'myfilter');

  echo '<pre>';
  echo 'json array{';

    foreach($result as $elem)  {
      echo(
        $elem['institutionID']. ", ".
        $elem['scientificNameID']. ", ".
        $elem['scientificName']. ", ".
        $elem['kingdom']. ", ".
        $elem['phylum']. ", ".
        $elem['class']. ", ".
        $elem['order']. ", ".
        $elem['family']. ", ".
        $elem['genus']. ", ".
        $elem['subgenus']
      );
      echo("<br/>");
    }
    echo '</pre>';
  //
    echo '}';
?>
```

edit:

original json code snippet:

```
[
  {
    "type": "",
    "modified": "",
    "language": "",
    "license": "",
    "rightsHolder": "",
    "accessRights": "",
    "bibliographicCitation": "",
    "references": "",
    "institutionID": "Phoneome10k",
    "collectionID": "",
    "datasetID": "",
    "institutionCode": "",
    "collectionCode": "",
    "datasetName": "",
    ...
```

Comment: maybe you have to convert $data with json_decode first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing this:

```
$data = file_get_contents("json/data.json");
```

```
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents("json/data.json"));
```

As file_get_contents returns a string, you encode it into an array using json_decode.

Comment: That gives: `Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array in`

Comment: I've added a snippet of the json code that was brought in. `var_dump($data);`  shows all the data as expected.

Comment: @SpatialDigger Just add `true` as a second parameter to `json_decode` to get an array instead of an `stdClass` object.

Comment: I've added `True` all the data is displayed, but the filter is not applied.

Comment: @SpatialDigger Now that becomes another question, doesn't it? Try to do some basic debugging, dump the values inside your filter function and try to identify why the matches aren't being made.

Comment: Ah my fault, using `| |` rather than `&&`